# FullCalendar jQuery plugin - set today date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar jQuery plugin  and I would like to set the today date.

I tried with this code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({year: 2012, month: 1, day: 25});
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', 2012, 01, 25);
```

But this set only the initial display date.

I would like current day become 25 of February and not today's current day 
(now today's date cell colored as current).

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: @giammin: thanks for your answer, I'll follow your advice. 
But I wonder is there way not to show current day at all?

Comment: I don't think you can hide the current day witouth a massive code rewrite. maybe you can override the css class to not show a different color for today date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short answer is no, you can't**

The problem you are experiencing is because the creators of this library set the `today` variable with the date taken from the client side and you cannot change or pass it as an option.

You can wait until this [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=593) is fulfilled or you can change the library by yourself.

A quick search returns 5 results for 'new Date()' which would need to be replaced.

You could replaced these occurrences with a custom constructor .